# How to check if a web element is displayed without crashing when trying to look for non-existing element?

Tags: scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to check id certain element is displayed with selenium, buy when you try to locate certain element like:

```
    val editInvoiceString = driver.findElement(By.xpath( """//*[@id="edit_invoice"]/div[2]/div/div[10]/div[5]/div[1]"""))
    editInvoiceString

if (editInvoiceString.isDisplayed)
do something
```

if the element is not on page the program will be crashed.

its crashing already in the assignment, cause there is a findElement there and its not finding the element

How can I check if it is displayed without crash it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just handle the `NoSuchElementException`:

```
try {
    val editInvoiceString = driver.findElement(By.xpath( """//*[@id="edit_invoice"]/div[2]/div/div[10]/div[5]/div[1]"""));
    println("element found");
    // check the displayedness
}
catch {
    case e: NoSuchElementException => println("no such element");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `driver.find` instead of `driver.findElement`, it will return an `Option`, on which you can then call `isDefined` to verify that the element is found.

Are you using [`WebBrowser`](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.0/index.html#org.scalatest.selenium.WebBrowser)?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by:

```
    public bool IsElementPresent(By by, IWebDriver driver)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.FindElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool IsElementPresent(By by, IWebDriver driver, int sec)
    {
        bool itemExist = false;

        itemExist = IsElementPresent(by, driver);
        while (!itemExist && sec >= 0)
        {
            thread.Sleep(1);
            itemExist = IsElementPresent(by, driver);
            sec--;
        }

        if (sec == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Call:

```
if(IsElementPresent(By.xpath("""//*[@id="edit_invoice"]/div[2]/div/div[10]/div[5]/div[1]"""),driver,5))
{
//case exist
}
else
{
// case not exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a try-catch clause if you ignore the exception using the Wait class (which extends FluentWait):

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)
   .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
   .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
   .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
WebElement foo = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
  By.xpath(".//*[@id="edit_invoice"]/div[2]/div/div[10]/div[5]/div[1]"))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use findElements instead of FindElement.

This will return a list of WebElements found.  If no elements are found the list will be empty.  It would look something like this (*Note* I'm not a Scala person so the syntax below may be slightly incorrect).

```
val editInvoiceString = driver.findElements(By.xpath( """//*[@id="edit_invoice"]/div[2]/div/div[10]/div[5]/div[1]"""))

if (editInvoiceString size > 0)
do something
```